# How do I properly test using a mocked service that returns a Promise?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine

I'm new to Angular and I'm still trying to figure out how things work for it. I'm currently having trouble testing a Component that depends on a Service that returns a `Promise`. The function I'm testing is structured like the following:

```
success: boolean;    

borrowBook() {
  this.bookService.borrow(this.selectedBook.id)
    .then(() => {
      this.success = true;
    })
    .catch((error: BorrowingError) => {
      this.success = false;
    });
}
```

Now, I'm not really sure if something like the code above is considered idiomatic, but that's how I wrote the code. In my unit test, I mocked the `bookService` using `jasmine.createSpyObj` function, and defined the stub as follows:

```
mockBookService.borrow.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(testResult));
```

However, my test fails saying that `component.success` is undefined when I expected it to be truthy. My test is programmed as follows:

```
it('test', async(() => {
  mockBookService.borrow.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(testResult));
  //setup pre-conditions here...
  component.borrowBook(();

  expect(component.success).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

My impression is that the expectations are being checked even before the Promise is handled accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chanced upon this [article about testing asynchronous code in Angular](https://netbasal.com/testing-asynchronous-code-in-angular-using-fakeasync-fc777f86ed13), which stated that the `flushMicrotasks` function can be used to run all the async components before checking expectations. This is only provided through the fake zone created through the `fakeAsync`, so in my code I used that instead of just `async`.

```
it('test', fakeAsync(() => { //used fakeAsync instead
  mockBookService.borrow.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(testResult));
  //setup pre-conditions here...
  component.borrowBook(();

  flushMicrotasks(); //added this before checking expectations
  expect(component.success).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

Comment: I think you can also do: `async(() => { comp.borrowBook(); fixture.whenStable(() => expect(...)) })`

Comment: @AndreiGătej I tried that and it didn't work for the rejection test case for some reason.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I misused the syntax. It should be: `fixture.whenStable().then(() => { expect(...) })`

Comment: No worries. I actually tried that with the correct syntax before trying this `flushMicrotask` approach and it still didn't work for the reject test case.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for sharing! I shall investigate this.